# Django decorator to restring users to delete or update others entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My site  has users and entries. I want to create a Django decorator to restring users to delete or update others entries.
But I have been able to do some.

I was thinking something like this

```
class EntryUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['...']
    ....

    @user_passes_test(lambda user: current.user.id == entry.user.id)
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EntryUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already using Class Based views, use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) instead of decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class EntryUpdate(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['...']

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user
```

Comment: Great it worked !!! but is this the best way to do it ?? is there other way using decorations  ?

Comment: If you using CBV this is best way to do, leave use of decorators for function based views